# Filter through an array and return Params

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to filter through an array of `data` from my API, however, the data returns unfiltered, I am thinking its something to do with the way I structured my method or It could be that my `params` are not being returned. I have below both my codes. I would really appreciate any effort. Thanks

**Trying to filter data**

```
    const [catalogueArray, setCatalogueArray] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

        catalogueList()

    }, [])

    const catalogueList = () => {

        const catalogue = data.filter(item => {
            item.storeName == navigation.state.params.enteredStore
            return { ...item }
        })
        setCatalogueArray(catalogue)
    }
```

**Setting Params**

```
const handleSelectedStore = (name) => {
      setSelectStore({ selectStore: name })
      navigation.navigate('StoreCatalogue', { selectStore: name })
    }
```

Comment: Show us the input and the desired output.

Comment: I have a data(api) with a few stores and when you click on a store... it gives you info, on that specific store... So currently the `data` returns all items from all stores in the api. I just need specific items from each store... items only under the storeName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an object, not a boolean in filter(). Objects are *truthy* so you are effectively doing no filtering at all and are getting the same result as if you did `return true`

The `==` comparison above the return is doing nothing since you aren't using the result of that comparison anywhere

The equality check is what you want to return. If you want new objects in the array you need a `map()` for that in another step

```
const catalogue = data.filter(item => {
     return item.storeName == navigation.state.params.enteredStore               
}).map(item => ({ ...item }));
```

Comment: Thank you @Charlietfl However `catalogue` returns an empty array `[ ]` when `console.log`ed and no data is returned. 

What I am trying to do is to return only specific items from the `enteredStore` So I want to filter though my API `data` and return only `items` specific to that store.

``

Comment: Ok well I have no idea what value of `navigation.state.params.enteredStore` is so you need to do some basic debugging of the values yourself

Comment: As for when no data has been returned from api yet you would expect it to be empty array

Comment: when I `console.log` `data` it has content from my api but `navigation.state.params.enteredStore` comes back `undefined`. I will post the solution if I have any luck, maybe I am just not explaining well enough. Thank you,

Comment: ok so you know what to look for now, feel free to accept answer if it helped

Comment: Not really. But I have a feeling the issue could be here `navigation.state.params.enteredStore`

Comment: oh definitely if it is undefined, inspect `navigation.state` and see what's there

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It was `navigation.state`